# Send nginx logs to both syslog and stdout/stderr

Tags: nginx, stdout, stderr, nginx-config

By default, my `nginx` server is plotting logs to `stdout` and `stderr`.

I want to forward logs to my syslog server, and I'm doing so successfully, from `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
  ...
  error_log syslog:server=localhost:5447,facility=local7,tag=nginx_client,severity=error;
  access_log syslog:server=localhost:5447,facility=local7,tag=nginx_client,severity=info;
  ...
}
```

How can I config my server to **also** plot the logs to `stdout` and `stderr`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just have multiple error_log and access_log entries inside your block

```
error_log syslog:server=localhost:5447,facility=local7,tag=nginx_client,severity=error;

access_log syslog:server=localhost:5447,facility=local7,tag=nginx_client,severity=info;

error_log stderr;
access_log /dev/stdout;
```

Should do the trick

Comment: It seems that order matters. When I put syslog below stdout - logs are not stored locally.